# Can the dot operator have an expression as right operand? Why?

Tags: c++

Is the following statement legal in any condition?

```
s.*p = 5;
```

So,
Can the dot operator have an expression as its right operand? Why?

Comment: It's not `.` with an expression.  It's `.*`: the *pointer to member* operator.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`p`is a **[pointer to member](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k8336763.aspx)** and you access the pointed member through a class object `s` using `.*`operator.

Comment: Is there actually a time when this is useful? I haven't ever had to use this, but I guess I've never had the right opportunity.

Comment: @chris: It is similar to a pointer variable just in this case the pointer is to a class member variable.So if you need a pointer to class member, this is what you use.Typical case is having a member function as callback function.A good read: [Pointer to member functions](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/pointers-to-members.html#faq-33.1)

Comment: Thanks, doesn't seem like I'll have any immediate use for it. The only callbacks I deal with were written without classes.